# appendChild does not put expand collapse icon in tree panel

Tags: extjs

expand/collapse icon is not shown after adding the child node to tree panel in extjs.

here i have a scenario where i get only immediate childrens of the node.  on getting the immediate childrens i want to add those to the selected node.

i can add the child nodes but the expand/collapse icon does not come up after adding the node.

following is my code.

```
onItemExpand : function(nodeinterface,eOpts)
{
    if(!nodeinterface.hasChildNodes())
    {
        nodeinterface.appendChild(dataFromES[0]);
    }
}
```

here the data contains the property **leaf:false** so that it can have more childs.

any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent node (in your case the nodeinterface variable) "leaf" property to false before you append a new child.

```
if(!nodeinterface.hasChildNodes())
{
    nodeinterface.set('leaf', false);
    nodeinterface.appendChild(dataFromES[0]);
}
```

Comment: here i am using itemExpand event, means parent node has the expand/collapse icon , but what about the children which i am going to add .

Comment: i got a workaround here , i add the child node with empty children key like children : [{}] , this shows up the expand collapse icon.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem and in my case the problem was related with the lack of the id property in the nodes.

I've added a random id when creating the nodes to append and then the expand/collapse icon is properly shown.

Alex